# Problem about radius and chord of a circle.

Tags: geometry, circles

The radius of a circle is 14. How far is a chord of length 12 away from the center of the circle?

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you draw a figure and label what you know?

Comment: I am not sure I know how to work with chord.

Comment: I was stuck the moment I saw chord.

Comment: Do you know that the centre of the circle is on the perpendicular bisector of a chord?

Comment: I did not know, but now I do.

Comment: I thought the the radius is the leg.

Comment: This is probably why I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are familiar with the Pythagorean theorem.
[image]

Comment: yes, I do know Pythagoras theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Isuckatgeometry, Good, then you shouldn't have any problem to understand this solution.

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

The chord is the vertical line here.  (Couldn't you look that up online trivially??)

[image]

Comment: The chord length is $12$ and we are asked for the distance from the center.